# Constructing $\omega_1$ sequences

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let A be an uncountable set  such that

(1) A is totally ordered by $<$,

(2) $\neg \exists x \forall y (x < y )$

(3) $\forall x,y \in A$ such that $x < y$ there exists a $z\in A$ such that $x < z < y$.

**Question:**: For any $u,v$ with $u<v$ and any countable ordinal  $\alpha$, there is a strictly increasing sequence of length $\alpha$ with $x_0>u$ and $x_{\alpha}=v$ ?

**My proof attempt:** Suppose the following generalization of dependent choice holds:

($DC_{\omega_1}$): If $R \subseteq A^{< \omega_1} \times A$ is total then there exists a function $f:\omega_1 \to A$ such that $R(f↾α,f(α))$ for all $\alpha< \omega_1$.

**Notice:** Here $A^{< \omega_1}$ denotes the set of all functions $f:\alpha \to A$ where $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal; $R$ is **total** means that for every such $f:\alpha \to A$ there is a $y \in A$ such that $R(f,y)$ holds.

Now, I define $R_{<}$ as follows: $\langle f_{\alpha}, x_{\alpha} \rangle < \langle f_{\beta}, x_{\beta} \rangle$  if $x_{\alpha}< x_{\beta}$ where $\alpha, \beta < \omega_1$. Now pick any $x_0 \in A$, given that $A$ is totally ordered I can  find  a $x_1$ such that  $x_0 < x_1$. This means that  $R_{\leq}$ is total. Thus,  for every $\langle \langle \alpha, x_\alpha \rangle, f(\alpha) \rangle$ (where $a< \omega$) there exists a $\langle \langle \beta, x_\beta \rangle, f(\beta) \rangle$ (where $\alpha< \beta$) such that  $\langle \langle \alpha, x_\alpha \rangle, f(\alpha) \rangle  R_{<} \langle \langle \beta, x_\beta \rangle, f(\beta) \rangle$.

Then I can construct the desired sequence as follows: By assumption (3) I know that there exists a $u_0$ such that $u < x_0 <  v$, so there exists $\langle \langle \gamma, x_0 \rangle, f(\gamma) \rangle$ for some $\gamma< \omega_1$. Then, I "choose" the smallest ordinal $\delta < \omega_1$ such that $ \langle \langle \gamma, x_\gamma \rangle, f(\gamma) \rangle  R_{<} \langle \langle \delta x_\delta \rangle, f(\delta) \rangle $. This $x_\delta$ becomes the second element of my sequence, i.e., $u < x_{0} <x_{\gamma} $. Then I repeat this process until I get my desired sequence.

Does this go in the right direction? I would appreciate help!

Comment: I don’t get the point of (4) unless $\le$ is a *strict* linear order, but then why this notation? (Also you seem to suddenly switch notation from $X$ to $A$...)

Comment: Also, what is the point of $\emptyset\notin X$? Everything else seems to just depend on what the relation $\le $ looks like, not anything to do with what the elements of $X$ actually are (as sets).

Comment: Dear @spaceisdarkgreen you are right, I edited accordingly the question!

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense, but still one more thing: You say $u < x_0 < x_1 ... < x_{\alpha} = v ?$, but what is $\alpha$ here? It seems like the sequence above $\alpha$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen $\alpha$ is an ordinal such that $\alpha < \omega_1$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Could you explain me what do you mean with the sequence above $\alpha $ irrelevant ?

Comment: I mean you are asserting the existence of a sequence of length $\omega_1$ and then saying that you require there is some $\alpha$ such that $u < x_0<\ldots x_\alpha=v,$ but that doesn't put any conditions on the values of the sequence for indices greater than $\alpha.$

Comment: Are you asking if for any $u,v$ with $u<v$ and any countable ordinal $\alpha$, there is a strictly increasing sequence of length $\alpha+1$ with $x_0>u$ and $x_\alpha = v$ ?

Comment: Dear @spaceisdarkgreen yes, thats what I am asking! But I guess I have counterexamples to this claim ... right ?  What about if I change the question to: for any u,v with u<v and any countable ordinal or uncountable  $\alpha$, there is a strictly increasing sequence of length $\alpha+1$ with $x_0>u$ and $x_{\alpha}=v$ ?

Comment: I don't understand how you would have counterexamples to the first case but not have counterexamples to the second case when you just also allow $\alpha$ to be uncountable, thus inviting more counterexamples. (I think it is true for countable $\alpha$ (and you don't even need $A$ to be uncountable), and false for $\alpha=\omega_1$, where the real numbers would serve as a counterexample.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, you are right! Thanks for clarifying this, I see what you mean!  I also edited my question accordingly. Could you please give me some hint/proof sketch of how you would prove it?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Every countable ordinal can be embedded in the rationals, just by a forth argument. If your order is dense then the rationals are embedded in every interval. The uncountable assumption has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @EddieChau If you have some interval $(u,v)$ for $u<v$ in a dense linear order, then any countable ordered set embeds into $(u,v).$ Just enumerate the elements of the ordered set as $X=a_0,a_1,\ldots$ and then construct the embedding $f:X\to (u,v)$ recursively: given $f(a_0)\ldots f(a_n)$ that preserve the ordering, you can always find a value for $f(a_{n+1})$ that continues to preserve the ordering since $(u,v)$ is densely ordered and without a least or greatest element.

Comment: You should read about Aronszajn and Suslin lines, in addition to the obvious counterexamples mentioned before.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks!!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the recomendation! Do you have some particular article/book in mind?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Wait! Wouldnt it be the case that your embedding will consider only finitely manny elements of X ?How do you consider the case  that we obtain that $x_{\alpha} = v$ where $\alpha= \omega+1$ ?

Comment: @EddieChau No, the recursion defines it at all $a_i$. For that case, you embed $\alpha$ into $(u,v)$ as above to get $x_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ and then you can just set $x_\alpha$ to $v.$