# Uncountable sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

**Question (1):** Let A be a dense total order where no countable subset is dense in any interval.  For any $u,v \in A$ with $u<v$ and  $\alpha=\omega_1$, is there a strictly increasing sequence of length $\alpha$ such that $u<x_0< ... <x_{\alpha}< v$ ?

My intuition is that such a sequence always exists as a consequence of the Axiom of choice and the density of A.

**Question (2):** However, can I **construct** such a sequence always?

Again my intuition is yes by transfinite recursion. But I don't know how to do it! Would appreciate any kind of help/suggestion.

Comment: It cannot be always possible. For instance, if $A$ is separable (i,e. $A$ has a countable dense set), such sequences there's not exists. More generally, if the length of the sequence is bigger than the density of your space, such sequence cannot exists.

Comment: This would say the cardinality of $A$ is larger than every cardinal...

Comment: Continuing from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4312623/constructing-omega-1-sequences, you need to specify more than "uncountable dense subset". You need to specify that no countable subset is dense in any interval. Otherwise there are many, many counterexamples. From $\Bbb R$, which is dense in $\Bbb R$; to the long line; etc. etc.

Comment: Dear @Gödel, thanks I did not think about this! What about now ( I edited the question) ?

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for pointing this out! I eddited accordingly the question! Does it work now?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem